# Why Guru Raghavendra Swamy has not wore Yagnopavitam in any photos?

Tags: tradition, yagnopavitam

Though Sri Guru Raghavendra Swamy belongs to Madhwa Brahmin community, I haven’t seen a single photo of his wearing Janivaara (Yagnopavitam i.e., sacred thread). Is it because he is not reserved to one community after entering to Vrindavan or all who take Sanyasa should remove Janivar? Please enlighten me here

Comment: May be due to his renunciation,  he stopped wearing janivar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sannyasis  generally remove tuft (shikha), sacred thread (Yagnopavitam) and carry an "Ekadanda" (single staff) when they enter into that stage of life. Sannyasis belonging to Dvaita sampradaya also follow the same. They also take the name "Tirtha" which is one among Dashanami Sampradaya. This is the reason they do not wear Yagnopavitam or shikha.

But sannyasis belonging to Sri Vaishnava sampradaya wear both Shikha,  Yagnopavitam and carry a Tridanda.

Comment: Any source references please to read further more on this since I am very interested.

Comment: @ssr1012 For which statement reference is needed? Tirtha is one of ten names among Dashanami Sampradaya. Sri Ananda Tirtha is the name of Madhwacharya.

Comment: Sannyasis wearing `Shikha` & `Yagnopavitam` and `Dvaita sampradaya. And `Raghavendra swamy ji` followed `Dvaitam` or `Vaishanavam`?

Comment: @ssr1012 Dvaita is a philosophy about relationship between Brahman and Jiva.  Vaishnavism is the faith. One can be both Dvaitan and Vaishnava or just one of them. Raghavendra Swamy (Raghavendra Tirtha is the name given as Sanyasa name.) was both Dvaitan and Vaishnavism.

Comment: Awesome guru...

Comment: @Moderator Which parts need references? Make it clear. Plain notice won't help and I won't add references unless you specify which one . It is already clear that every Dvaita sanyasi has the name Tirtha at the end of their name